# Compare two collection based upon an element and concatenate in java

Tags: java, join, collections, compare

I've two collections which has data in terms of key-value pair which is retrieved from database.

```
Collection<Map<String, Comparable>> user1 = function.call(.....);
Collection<Map<String, Comparable>> user2 = function2.call(....)
```

I want to compare these two collections based upon a key date, if they are equal then append other list to first list.

Lets say the key name on both of the collection is different.
Example -

```
user1 - {price_id, user_id, price_created}
user2 - {delivary_id, user_id, delivery_created, delivery_metadata}
```

**Input example** - Note that data format across two data is different, I'll trim the data and compare.

user1 data - {price_id=1, user_id=1, **price_created=2013-02-10**}
{price_id=2, user_id=2, **price_created=2013-02-11**}
{price_id=3, user_id=3, **price_created=2013-12-12**}

user2 data - {delivary_id =1, user_id=1, **delivery_created=2013-02-10 06:33:08.0**, delivery_metadata='test user2 NE'}
{delivary_id =2, user_id=2, **delivery_created = 2013-12-10 06:33:08.0**, delivery_metadata='test user2 NE'}
{delivary_id =3, user_id =3, **delivery_created=2013-12-12 06:33:08.0**, delivery_metadata='test user2 NE'}

**Expected output example-** like an inner join(1 and 3 row has been comapared with price_created and  delivery_created).

{price_id=1, user_id=1, price_created=2013-02-10, delivary_id =1, user_id=1, delivery_created=2013-02-10 06:33:08.0, delivery_metadata='test user2 NE' }

{price_id=3, user_id=3, price_created=2013-12-12, delivary_id =3, user_id =3, delivery_created=2013-12-12 06:33:08.0, delivery_metadata='test user2 NE' }

If i want to compare `price_created` of the first user1 and `delivery_created` on the user2, how can i perform that? I tried using addAll in collections but could not pass parameter to compare.

Help and right direction appreciated, I'd never solved a problem like this. This reminds why SQL was introduced along with powerful joins, aggregation tools! Well my mentor doesn't want to use SQL, so stuck at java.

Cleared on my own, thanks!

Comment: can you add some input and output in your question

Comment: @ByteCode Added an input and output example to make things more clear, thanks!